# i have 5 worksheets in my excel workbook but i want to specifically protect 3rd and 5th worksheets with password

Tags: vba, excel

I have 5 worksheets in my excel workbook but I want specifically protect 3rd and 5th worksheets with password. Have below macro which protects only one sheet. what needs to be added to protect more than one sheet but not all sheets.  Kindly guide me.

Thanks in Advance!!

```
      Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
      Dim MySheets As String, Response As String
      MySheet = "Sheet1"
      If ActiveSheet.Name = MySheet Then
      ActiveSheet.Visible = False
            Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")
             If Response = "pass" Then
             Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
             Application.EnableEvents = False
             Sheets(MySheet).Select
              Application.EnableEvents = True
              End If
       End If
       Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim MySheets As String, Response As String
MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name
Select Case MySheet
Case "Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet5"
ActiveSheet.Visible = False
     Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")
      If Response = "pass" Then
        Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets(MySheet).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
      End If
End Select
Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
End Sub
```

But hardcoding the password doesnt make it that safe.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Its working fine. Thanks a lot once again

Comment: @UGP.one more concern. While typing password its reflecting the actual character, instead of that " * " needs to be displayed. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: You cannot achieve this in an `InputBox`, you have to create a `Userform` for this. If you then use a `Textbox` you can set a password character.

Comment: I will do that .Thanks@UGP

Comment: @UGP.I have "n" of worksheet in my workbook.  I want to protect worksheet with password till (n-1)th worksheet . Is there any shortcut to use in vba program instead of mentioning all the worksheet name one by one . Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `ActiveSheet.Index` and then you can say `Case 1 to 5` for example.